# Firebase promise returns nonsense object

Tags: firebase, promise, firebase-realtime-database, response

I'm playing with different ways of using Firebase(promises) and Angularfire(observables). I've noticed that when I run a query with Firebase, the promise returns a non-sense object.

```
userRef = firebase.database().ref('/users')
                .equalTo(member.email, 'email')
                .once('value');
userRef.then(res => console.log(res));
```

output is something like:

```
W {A: P, U: V, g: $d}.
```

You can dig down into that object, but since none of the keys are labeled anything intelligible like 'data' or 'response' it's hard to 1) track down where, if anywhere, my data might be or 2) even look up in the docs what kind of object I'm getting and why. All I know is that it doesn't have .then or .subscribe methods, so it's not a promise or an observable.

What am I getting, and what can I do to actually get the user I'm requesting?

Answer (score 2):

What the firebase promise return is a `snapshot`. You need to call `val()` to get the value you want.

From the [official blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html):

```
ref.child('blogposts').child(id).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  // The Promise was "fulfilled" (it succeeded).
  renderBlog(snapshot.val());
}, function(error) {
  // The Promise was rejected.
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: I would have said yes, that's it, except that I know that query returns an entry (I've run it before), and the val on that object returns null. So I'm wondering if it's actually some poorly formatted error.